# How to multiply a vector4 with matrix4x4 in Unity?

Tags: unity

If I would like to multiply a `Vector4` with a `Matrix4x4` in Unity, what method can I use? I have only found `Matrix4x4.MultiplyVector()`, but as far as I understand this is for multiplying a matrix with a vector and this type of multiplication is not commutative.

Actually I am looking for the equivalent forms of `XMVector3Transform` and `XMVector3TransformCoord`.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative, full stop. You'll never get around that because spatial transformations themselves are not commutative. If you want to transform a relative/direction vector (w = 0, ignoring translation) then MultiplyVector is the right method. If you want to transform an absolute position vector (w = 1, including translation) then use MultiplyPoint. If you want something else, it would be good to **edit your question** to explain in more detail what you want and how it differs from these two methods.